# How to properly use `return` for `render`: DoubleRenderError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, rendering

I'm new to json and experience a problem with returning. I get the error below, even though everywhere I `render`, I also `return`. What causes this error?

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Api::V1::ArticlesController#show
>   Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

The error refers to `render json: {errors: "not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized` in `def authenticate_user` below. Instead, I would expect it to just render a json error: "not authorized". Any idea why this is not happening?

```
before_action :authenticate
def authenticate
  unless authenticated?
    render json: {errors: "not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized
    return
  end
end
```

This calls on the following helper methods:

```
def authenticated?
  !current_user.nil?
end

def current_user
  token = request.headers["Authorization"]
  email = request.headers["HTTP_USER_EMAIL"]
  if token
    user = User.friendly.find_by(email: email)
    if user
      if user.token_expired?
        render json: {errors: "Session expired, please login" }, status: :unauthorized
        return
      elsif user.authenticated?(token)
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

**Update:** The solutions provided to remove `return` everywhere work, but I don't understand why. Suppose the helper method looks like the one below. Then it would be important to include `return`, right? because otherwise if @node isn't found, the method would still continue and the message "node not found" would not be displayed. Could you explain?

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find_by(id: params[:node_id])
    if @node.nil?
      render json: { errors: "node not found" }, status: :bad_request
      return
    end
    nodee = @node.create(create_params)
    if nodee.save
      render json: @node, status: :created
    else
      render json: @node, status: :bad_request
    end
  end
```

In other words, I would have expected that removing `render` from `def authenticate` would result in Rails just continuing to the `create` method, since `def authenticate` didn't tell it to step there (which is how I see `render`).

**Update2:** I can also not remove `render` as suggested in the answers, but instead move it to the beginning of the line: `return render json: {errors: "not authorized" }, status: :unauthorized`. Would love to understand why this is.

Comment: remove `return` from `authenticate` method

Comment: remove the `return` from your `authenticate` method and `current_user` method.

Comment: Thanks, removing `render` works. But I don't understand it. Could you please have a look at the update added to the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core issue is that `current_user` is doing a render itself - this is unusual and makes it very easy to accidentally render twice. The second thing is that a before filter halts processing of the action if render or redirect are called during the filter: returning from the filter doesn't directly impact things.

Removing the return from `current_user` works largely by accident: this means that the return value from `current_user` is the return value from render, ie is no longer nil. This means that `authenticated?` returns true (even though the user isn't authenticated) so your before filter doesn't render a second time. Rails then stops execution of the action since render was called from within  a filter so it appears that things have worked.

In general though you do need to call return to stop the rest of the method executing, however this obviously doesn't stop process inside the calling method.

Personally I would leave authenticate as is but change current_user so that it doesn't have any side effects (other than setting @current_user). If you really want to change the error message then track the reason why current_user is nil in a separate instance variable (in truth I probably wouldn't be rolling my own authentication but that's another story)

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot to understand and to improve `current_user`!

Answer (score 0):

For future travelers:

When using guard clauses and helper methods in your rails API controllers to avoid multi-line if else chains, do this:

1. Rename helper methods to ? methods
2. Return if helper_methods? returns true
3. In helper method, make sure to return true if the condition is met

Cheers

`def controller_method`

```
return if invalid_email?(params["user"]["email"])
...
def invalid_email?(email)
  if EmailValidator.invalid?(email) then render(json: { status: 422, message: "Your email format is invalid. Please check that your email is correct and try again!" }, status: 422) and return true end
end
```